# What's the use of overriding javax.servlet.Servlet.getServletInfo()?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I see plenty of servlet examples that override the getServletInfo() method (and I regularily do this myself). However, I wonder if there's any use in doing this? I would expect for example that the tomcat manager application to display such information in the list of applications or the status page, but this isn't the case. So:

- any webservers/generic management application actually displaying this information?
- any other ways to regularily make use of this information/method?

Answer (score -2):

public abstract String getServletInfo()
It is an abstract method so if you want to create UserDefineServlet using implements javax.servlet.Servlet interface so you have to override unimplemented method getServletInfo() in this method you define info about servlet. 
Returns a string containing information about the servlet, such as its author, version, and copyright. As this method may be called to display such information in an administrative tool that is servlet engine specfic, the string that this method returns should be plain text and not contain markup.
Example:
    import java.io.*;

    import javax.servlet.*;

```
public class First implements Servlet{  
ServletConfig config=null;  

public void init(ServletConfig config){  
this.config=config;  
System.out.println("servlet is initialized");  
}  

public void service(ServletRequest req,ServletResponse res)  
throws IOException,ServletException{  

res.setContentType("text/html");  

PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();  
out.print("<html><body>");  
out.print("<b>hello simple servlet</b>");  
out.print("</body></html>");  

}  
public void destroy(){System.out.println("servlet is destroyed");}  
public ServletConfig getServletConfig(){return config;}  
public String getServletInfo(){return "copyright 2007-1010";}  

}
```

Comment: Please consider formatting your answer accordingly.

Comment: It is not abstract in `GenericServlet`, and therefore not in`HttpServlet` either, so you don't have to override it at all in practice.

Comment: I mentioned if want to create user define Servlet using implements javax.servlet.Servlet interface directly. Servlet interface defines methods that all servlets must implement. The Servlet interface is the root interface of the servlet class hierarchy. All Servlets need to either directly or indirectly implement the Servlet interface. The GenericServlet class of the Servlet API implements the Servlet interface. In addition to the Servlet interface.

Comment: Thanks for taking on my question. However, the question is not about how to implement/override, but rather focusses on "an administrative tool that is servlet engine specfic". Does anyone know of such a tool that actually uses this method and displays the information returned? Apparently, Tomcat (or more correct: its manager application) does not.